# What's a good way to unenqueue all scripts for a single template page?

Tags: themes, templates, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I've found that my attachment templates are inheriting the [enqueued](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) scripts for single posts. My first instinct was to unenqueue these scripts one-by-one or to do an `is_attachment()` check before enqueueing them at all.

It strikes me that a more robust way to do this might be to simply be to remove any and all enqueued scripts for that page type; that way, I don't have to update code in multiple places if I add or remove an enqueued script in the future.

Offhand I can't find a way to do this. What's a good way to unenqueue all scripts for just a single page?

Comment: Why would you want to unenqueue them? If you do that, then things like comments and such won't work properly.

Comment: These are my own custom scripts I'd like to unenqueue -- and, incidentally, on pages without comments. If I'm missing something important, I'd rather start with a blank slate and add the one or two I need rather than have to explicitly unenqueue a half dozen or so.

Comment: I've thought of playing with the `$wp_scripts` global but I'm worried I'm going to unenqueue scripts on more than just the current page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but this might do it:

```
global $wp_scripts;
if (is_a($wp_scripts, 'WP_Scripts')) {
  $wp_scripts->queue = array();
}
```

Basically just resetting the scripts queue to blank. Should work, I think. You'd want this right at the top of your attachment template, probably.

From an optimization perspective, it would be faster to use the is_attachment() method to not enqueue the ones you want at all instead.

Comment: But be aware of your php version before using `is_a()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php - look at the notes for version and deprecated

Comment: WordPress itself uses is_a() for this, which is why I used it.

Comment: @kaiser: `is_a()` is used because `instanceof` was introduced in PHP 5, and WordPress currently still supports `instanceof`. And it appears `is_a()` is no longer deprecated in 5.3 - what do you call a "no-longer-deprecated" function?

Comment: i know about the usage. I haven't known about is_a() before i found it used in wp core. @Jan: what do you call a "no-longer-deprecated" function? ... honestly i don't know. I just said/wrote that he should take a look at his php version before usage. Did i say something wrong? Sry, pretty tired at the moment. Long day + night.